# Prove that $W_1 + W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing both $W_1$and $W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So I've been looking at the proof for this, and there's one thing I don't understand:

> Let $U$ be some subspace of $V$, we need to show if $W_1 \subseteq U$, 
>   and if $W_2 \subseteq U$. Then $W_1 + W_2 \subseteq U$.

Thing is, I don't see WHY we need to show $W_1 + W_2 \subseteq U$. That is, I don't understand how showing that proves $W_1 + W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$and $W_2$?

Comment: It does not prove it. We also need to show that $W_1+W_2$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah should have mentioned, we've already proved that. This is part (ii).

Comment: $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspace of $V$ and do you want to prove $W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear before.

Comment: Given that you have already done half, all we need to do is to show that any subspace $U$ of $V$ that contains $W_1$ and $W_2$ contains $W_1+W_2$. Let $w_1+w_2\in W_1+W_2$, where $w_1\in W_1$ and $w_2\in W_2$. Then $w_1\in U$ and $w_2\in U$. It follows that $w_1+w_2\in U$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but why does showing that any subspace $U$ of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ contains $W_1 + W_2$ show that $W_1 + W_2$  is the smallest subspace that contains $W_1$ and $W_2$?

Comment: It means that no **proper** subspace of $W_1+W_2$ can contain both $W_1$ and  $W_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any subspace D of V containing $W_1$ and $W_2$. Then elements of the subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ are contained in D and therefore any linear combination of elements of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is contained in D since D is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore any v in $L(W_1 \cup W_2)$ is contained in D which implies that $W_1+W_2=L(W_1 \cup W_2)$ is contained in $D$.

This means that if any subspace of $U$ contains $W_1$ and $W_2$ then it must contain $W_1+W_2$ which implies that $W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace containing $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: Can you clarify what the $L$ in $L(W_1 \cup W_2)$ means?

Comment: $L$ in $L(W_1 \cup W_2)$ denotes the linear span of $W_1 \cup W_2$ that is the set of all linear combinations of elements of $W_1$ and $W_2$.This is how $W_1 + W_2$ is defined.